# React Native links did not work when disabling Safari from the Allowed Apps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, react-native, safari, linker

We are using react native' [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) for opening URLs. Its working for normally, but when some iPhone users disables safari (for some security reasons), the links stop working.

Steps to disable Safari

Settings -> Screen Time -> Content and Privacy Restrictions -> Allowed Apps -> Safari -> turn off

I have debug and following error is recorded

**-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "https://www.instagram.com/smyasir" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme https"**

Info Plist settings are intact and it does't matter if url is http or https, and is of facebook or linkedin or instagram, it simply does not work when safari is disabled, otherwise all urls work fine.